# How do I switch from 1 database to 1 database per subdomain rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multi-tenant, saas, multi-database

I have a multi-tenancy app where everything is stored in 1 Postgres database. All models have a account_id, so the data a customer can see is based on his account_id. This works perfect, but due to security and privacy concerns, customers demand that their data is stored in a separate database. So what do I need to do to make this happen? When a custome logs in, then you connect to its own database? And what is the best way to migrate the current data to the several customer databases?

I try appartment gem

Comment: If this is a demand then I would recommend moving away from multi-tenancy and charge the customers for siloed hosting. Just deploy the app to N locations, with N databases and charge for the individual hosting and db administration. When deploying you can just deploy to all sites.

Comment: One database per customer might seem like a good idea now, but trust me, it will quickly become a living nightmare for you and your team and you will regret it. These become near impossible to maintain when you go beyond a trivial number of customers. Use a single database, and use *horizontal sharding*, a feature now part of Rails, to work at scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making seperate database try to do with different schema.

It means create different tenant for each customer in db. In ***psql*** by default it supports the multitenancy concept.

When you are planned to use ***apartment gem*** that was the best choice for requirement. Because it makes much easier when come to handling multi-tenant logics.

With help of that you can separate each customer's data isolated from another customer. I have also used this methodology, it worked out for me very perfectly.

One database per customer definitely maintaining and scaling is painful one.

Hope this might helps you :)